# Process with an ID #### is not running in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to run an solution in visual studio 2015 created in visual studio 2017. When i am going to run this then it says "Local host refused to connect"
i have already tried the follwing steps to overcome this error.

1-  [Remove Development Server Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sQi2.png)

2- [Add _CSRUN_DISABLE_WORKSAROUND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O284L.png)

i have tried these two steps but problem is still exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

close vs then go to the folder of your project and delete the .vs folder, then start vs again and try running your application. This worked for me.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this was the solution for me. In my case I was sharing my solution in several computers via dropbox. I guess that messed some file inside de .vs folder.